# Multiple Weekdays Selection for Android

Tags: java, android

I´m trying to create a layout where users can select multiple weekdays. A simple line with Sunday to Saturday `Buttons`. User can check multiple `Buttons` and I send that selection to my database.

As far as my knowledge, once I get the values I can send them to my database, I only need a way to create that multiple choice selector.

Comment: You only need multiple buttons in your layout. What do you need more?

Comment: I would take a look at the calender view widget... http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CalendarView.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have 2 options:

1- Can use a DatePicker, here a simple example to use. http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-date-picker-example/

2- If you need only days, no numbers, months, etc.You can use a Multiple Selection ListView, is a ListView with select option for each.

Comment: I finally did this:
In onCreate:
                    sunday   = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.sunday);
                    monday      = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.monday);
                    tuesday    = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.tuesday);
                    wednesday    = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.wednesday);
                    thursday    = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.thursday);
                    friday    = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.friday);
                    saturday    = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.saturday);

Then in setOnClickListener I collect all true/false result